# Vue blog change rendered post when clicked on a link from "latest posts" sidebar

Tags: vue.js, sidebar

I've got a problem with my hobby project, I created a BlogPost.vue in which I render the previously clicked post from a Blog.vue page.

In this BlogPost, I render the clicked post's title, content etc, and on the sidebar, I show a small area in which I render 3 of the latest posts from this same category - the posts from Blog.vue.

When I click on the sidebar's links, any of the 3, the browser does change the slug, and the page does re-render itself, except it re-renders the same post that was clicked. If I refresh the page in the browser (or Ctrl+R or F5 etc), then it does render the correct content clicked from this sidebar.

I have no clue why it does that, I can only suppose that I should be watching the route change then somehow refresh what it renders, but no idea as to how.

Blog.vue, this works great, renders the single post clicked

```
    <script setup lang="ts">
import axios from "axios";
import { ref } from "vue";
import { onMounted } from "vue";
import moment from "moment";

const postsUrl = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
const posts = ref([] as any);

const isLoading = ref(false);
const errorCaught = ref(false);

var queryOptions = {
  _embed: true,
};

const getPosts = () => {
  isLoading.value = true;

  axios
    .get(postsUrl, { params: queryOptions })
    .then((response) => {
      posts.value = response.data;
      console.log(posts.value);
      isLoading.value = false;
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log(isLoading.value);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error) {
        isLoading.value = false;
        errorCaught.value = true;
      }
    });
};

onMounted(async () => {
  getPosts();
});
</script>

<template>
  <transition name="fadeLoading">
    <div v-if="isLoading" class="posts-loading">
      <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
  </transition>
  <transition name="fadeLoading">
    <div class="errorCaught" v-if="errorCaught">
      There was an error loading news
    </div>
  </transition>
  <div class="blog-container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <transition-group name="fadeBlog">
        <ul v-if="!isLoading" class="blog-posts-ul" v-for="post in posts">
          <div class="posts-card">
            <a
              ><router-link
                :to="/blog/ + post.slug"
                key="post.id"
                class="posts-permalink"
              >
              </router-link
            ></a>
            <img
              v-if="post.featured_media != 0"
              class="posts-featuredimage"
              :src="post._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url"
              :alt="post.title.rendered"
            />
            <img v-else src="@/assets/logos/favicon-big.png" />
            <div class="posts-date">
              <p>
                {{ moment(post.date).fromNow() + " " + "ago" }}
              </p>
            </div>

            <div class="posts-text">
              <h1 class="posts-title">{{ post.title.rendered }}</h1>

              <p v-html="post.excerpt.rendered" class="posts-excerpt"></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </transition-group>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

BlogPost.vue, renders the previously clicked one, but does not show the sidebar's clicked content

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch, onMounted } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
import axios from "axios";
import moment from "moment";

const route = useRoute();

const postsUrl = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
const queryOptions = {
  slug: route.params.blogSlug,
  _embed: true,
};
const post = ref([] as any);
const isLoading = ref(false);

const latestPostsAPI = "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
const latestPosts = ref([] as any);

const errorCaughtLatest = ref(false);

var queryOptionsLatest = {
  _embed: true,
  per_page:3,
};

const getLatest = () => {
  axios
    .get(latestPostsAPI, { params: queryOptionsLatest })
    .then((response) => {
      latestPosts.value = response.data;
      console.log(latestPosts.value);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error) {
        errorCaughtLatest.value = true;
      }
    });
};

const getPost = () => {
  isLoading.value = true;
  axios
    .get(postsUrl, { params: queryOptions })
    .then((response) => {
      post.value = response.data;
      console.log("Pages retrieved!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(() => {
      isLoading.value = false;
    });
};

getLatest();
getPost();

</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="!isLoading" class="post-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="post-title">{{ post[0].title.rendered }}</div>
      <div class="post-date">
        {{ moment(post[0].date).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm, dddd") }}
      </div>
      <!-- THIS INCLUDES HTML TAGS -->
      <div class="post-content" v-html="post[0].content.rendered"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="side-container">
    <div class="side-wrapper">
      <ul v-if="!isLoading" class="blog-posts-ul" v-for="latest in latestPosts">
        <div class="posts-card">
          <a
            ><router-link
              :to="/blog/ + latest.slug"
              key="latest.id"
              class="posts-permalink"
            >
            </router-link
          ></a>
          <img
            v-if="latest.featured_media != 0"
            class="posts-featuredimage"
            :src="latest._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url"
            :alt="latest.title.rendered"
          />
          <img v-else src="@/assets/logos/favicon-big.png" />
          <div class="posts-text">
            <div class="posts-title">{{ latest.title.rendered }}</div>
            <div class="posts-date">
              <p>{{ moment(latest.date).fromNow() + " " + "ago" }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="posts-author">
              {{ latest._embedded.author[0].name }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: Hey, some code information would do great.

Comment: Sorry forgot, bit hasty, corrected :)

Comment: I guess a simple `watch(() => route.params.blogSlug, () => getLatest())` would do the trick?

Comment: Check if this works on production. I have the same issue but it's only present occassionally and only in development.

Comment: @Kapcash Nope watch+getLatest not doing anything. I load the actual content with getPost(), the getLatest() is only for the sidebar which shows the latest 3 posts. Somehow, I should be loading the NEW slug into the getPost() function WHEN I click on the sidebar's links. Sidebar's links are :to=/blog/ + latest.slug, coming from latest in latestPosts. That DOES get shown in the browsers link bar correctly AFTER I click on the link. But, the render stays the same, which indicates that the getPost() doesnt load in with the NEW params (slug: route.params.blogSlug).

Comment: @BernardBorg Sorry, but no, ran npm run build, then npm run preview, same exact behavior, the render doesnt update based on the sidebar's links (or based on the NEW route.params.blogSLug)

Comment: And a `watch` + `getPost` doesn't help either? I guess because the current page is already mounted, when you click another link, it must render the same component and Vue take advantage of this to not re-render the entire page (so mounted is called only once)

Comment: @Kapcash Yes after your idea, I tried watch + getPost too, and no, its the same behavior. Maybe I should run this watch+getPost in another lifecycle? Will try

Comment: No, still unsuccessfull, no render of clicked post from the sidebar, only re-renders the same content, yet changes the browser bar's link to the correct slug.

Comment: @Kapcash, I got it, slipped  my mind it might be the problem and it is, will post the problem solving method in a moment

Comment: @BernardBorg  got it, slipped my mind it might be the problem and it is, will post the problem solving method in a moment

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Just an advice, learn how to properly debug your code: put breakpoints in your code to see if your methods are executed, check the Network tab if your query has been done and with which params... This will save you time :)

Comment: @Kapcash thx for the advice, thats always what I do, leaving  a console.log at every junction where I want to check if right after it or before, other lines run well or not. I also always work with the dev panel open, checking all and everything that is connected to the supposed "wrong code part". But this was just an overlook and the code itself was correct, I just forget I saved something that should be reactive, as a simple constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my original post as you can see, I'm using `axios` to get my post with the `params` `queryOptions`:

I declare my queryOptions with a ***const***:

```
const queryOptions = {
  slug: route.params.blogSlug,
  _embed: true,
};
```

THEN, I call the getPost method, which uses this constant:

```
const getPost = () => {
  isLoading.value = true;
  axios
    .get(postsUrl, { params: queryOptions } })
    .then((response) => {
      post.value = response.data;
      console.log("getPost!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(() => {
      isLoading.value = false;
    });
};
```

And the problem is right there: that `queryOptions`, IS a ***constant***, gets defined at the onMounted lifecycle, or even before I'm not 100% sure, but ***it does NOT get re-defined WHEN I click on any link on this BlogPost.vue component.***

****SO, the solving is the following:****

Change the **`getPost`** method so it does NOT use a pre-defined constant, rather just simply type in the params, like the following:

```
const getPost = () => {
  isLoading.value = true;
  axios
    .get(postsUrl, { params: { slug: route.params.blogSlug, _embed: true } })
    .then((response) => {
      post.value = response.data;
      console.log("getPost!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    })
    .then(() => {
      isLoading.value = false;
    });
};
```

If I do it this way, every time the `getPost` method runs, which it WILL since I'm watching the `blogSlug` change with

```
watch(() => route.params.blogSlug, getPost);
```

the **`getPost`** function will always call the latest `route.params.blogSlug`, which gets changed ***before*** the watcher runs the `getPost` as I click on the sidebar link.